# Google Maps and Backbone.js event triggering

Tags: backbone.js, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Map where user can click (on the map everywhere), the click event opens a Bootstrap modal window, contained a form. My question is, how/where to handle this submit event to add a marker to the marker collection, save it to the db, etc.

Currently I have a Map View, that renders the google map, and adds an event listener for the click. Clicking on the map opens the Modal.

```
App.Views.Map = Backbone.View.extend({
...
initializeMap : function(){}
...
addMapEventlistener : function() {

    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'dblclick', function(event) {

    var coords = event.latLng.toUrlValue();

    var carray = coords.split(",");

    var model = new Backbone.Model({ coords: carray });

    var view = new App.Views.Modal({ model: model });

    var $modalEl = $("#modal");
    $modalEl.html(view.render().el);
    $modalEl.modal();
    }); 
}    


App.Views.App = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function() {

var addMarkerView = new App.Views.AddMarker({ collection: App.markers });

        }

});

// add marker view

    App.Views.AddMarker = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: '#addForm',

        initialize: function() {

            $('<input>', {
                type: 'submit',
                value: 'Submit',
                class: 'smt'
            }).appendTo(this.$el);

            console.log('AddMarker init run'); // this echoed out

        },

        events: {
            'submit' : 'addMarker'      
        },

        addMarker: function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            alert('hello');

        },

    });
```

my guess is that the form rendered after the click event on the map, so I have to set backbone event listening somehow after the modal opens, and handle the form submission in a collection view, right?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [events](http://backbonejs.org/#View) object to bind your listeners.
About when (re)binding your events. When the view is instantiated, the listeners specified in the events object will be bound **to the view element**. This implies that if your event targets a child element, the fact that the child exists or not at that moment doesn't matter. Now, you'll have to rebind your listeners in the special case where **you change your view element without the setElement method**.

Example:

```
<div id="#mydiv"></div>
```

And you want to bind an event on the buttons inside this div (you'll create some afterwards.).
Well, [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/gVJ7N/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It doesn't add the submit button to the form, even the initialize method runs. Again, this views run before I click on the map, so this time the form is only in the template, so not "live". This way surely can't add the submit button to the form.

Edited the main post ^

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved. My bad. I added events to the wrong view, I have to add it to the App.Views.Modal view (of course the event happens in the modal). Thanks for the time!